# How to use AM/PM format with the calendar function in moment js

Tags: javascript, calendar, momentjs

I have this

```
return moment(dateString).calendar() //? Mañana a las 15:00
```

On the [docs](https://momentjs.com/#calendar-time) it shows the format I want (PM/AM).
And I can't run `format()` before because it returns a string

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) the strings coming from the `calendar()` are localized. So based on your location you would see the `PM` or not. If you want to force it you would need to [change your locale](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/).

> These strings are localized, [and can be customized](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/).